SDk library ->@sap-cloud-sdk/http-client
We are using Cloud SDk library  ->@sap-cloud-sdk/http-client - npm (npmjs.com) and it function executeHttpRequest to send request to convergent mediation system(On premise ) via cloud connector .The connectivity is made using Destination which is mainatained in BTP subaccount.
Issue : when we send request to Microservice on particular endpoint. Cloud connector logs shows three requests being fired at the same time even though we send the request once.
const { executeHttpRequest } = require('@sap-cloud-sdk/http-client');
   const express = require('express'); const app = express();
   app.use(express.json());
   
   app.post('/xyz', async (req, res) => {
       try {
           async function callPostApi(req, destination) {
               const response = await executeHttpRequest(
                   {
                       destinationName: destination,
                   },
                   {
                       method: 'POST',
                       url: req.url,
                       data: req.body,
                       maxContentLength: Infinity,
                       maxBodyLength: Infinity,
                       headers: {
                           "Content-Type": "application/json"
                       },
                   }
               );
               return response.data;
           }
           const responseData = await callPostApi(req, "Destination Name");
           res.status(200).send(responseData);
   
       } catch (error) {
           console.error('Error:', error);
           res.status(500).send({ message: "An error occurred", error });
       } });


The reason is that SDK makes additional calls to fetch CSRF tokens by default for POST requests. This can be turned off by setting:
{
  fetchCsrfToken: false
}

as the 3rd parameter of the executeHttpRequest function. Further documentation can be found here
